# how to find out where a missing route is defined with nuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, static-site, nuxtjs

I'm getting an error on a static nuxtJS site, and it's been awhile since I worked on this.
How can I find where this is defined or referenced? Simple searching/grep doesn't help.

> ERROR  Error generating route "/case/ikea": This page could not be found

There is an `ikea` page in a different directory but I can't find any references to the path above. Have tried `rm -rf dist` in case it's a ghost file from an old build, but no luck.

Are dynamic paths used in some way beyond just files in the `/pages/` dir?

Thanks!

Comment: `.nuxt` then `router.js` then find -> "case" within the document. Also, there is the ability to register these routes through [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#extendroutes) within the `nuxt.config.(js|ts)` file.

Comment: thanks for the comment. there is no route in the `.nuxt/router.js` - which is a built file as far as I can see. presumably based on files in /pages/. 
bizarro